# What is the Linux equivalent of SNMPc network manager?

Tags: linux, snmp

I need Linux based open-source SNMP management system. Castle Rock's SNMPc is an excellent tool but supports only windows. What is the equivalent to SNMPc in the Linux world????

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there are literally hundreds of both opensource and licensed software packages for network and server management. a simple google search renders a comparison to some of the software out there [see it here](http://network-automation.virtual-strategy.com/). this is most likely why you are getting down voted as you have seemed to not put any real research into your question.

however, one suggestion is opennms. it is free, opensource and linux based here